# How to set the "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to "Yes" by default in Magento Admin >Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

My client has a requirement that while adding a new attribute, the field "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" should be set to Yes by default. I tried looking for the form but am not being able to figure out from where this value is being rendered. Where can I find the file from where this form is being rendered? Thanks in advance.